# Code coverage results not appearing in VS 2013 using Chutzpah

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, chutzpah

I have configured Chutzpah nuget package in VS 2013 Premium.
I am using jasmine to write my test cases, <s>I am able to see the tests are running on the Unit test windows</s> but I am not able to see the <s>Code coverage results</s> tests and code coverage for my javascript code. The browser doesnt show the code coverage results.

Note: I am not able to see tests and coverage both, below window is from Resharper which recognises the tests.

[image]

My chutzpah.json file looks like this:

```
{
"Framework" : "jasmine",
"TestHarnessReferenceMode": "AMD",
"TestHarnessLocationMode": "SettingsFileAdjacent",
"References":[
    { "Path" : "../../Views/Claim/Startup/ClaimStartup.main.js"},
    { "Path" : "../../Scripts/jasmine-2.7.0/jasmine_favicon.png"},
    { "Path" : "../../Scripts/jasmine-2.7.0/jasmine.css"},
    { "Path" : "../../Scripts/jasmine-2.7.0/jasmine.js" },
    { "Path" : "../../Scripts/jasmine-2.7.0/jasmine-html.js"},
    { "Path" : "../../Scripts/jasmine-2.7.0/boot.js" },
    { "Path" : "../../Scripts/jquery/1.10.2/jquery-1.10.2.js"},
    { "Path" : "../../Scripts/Common.js"},
    { "Path" : "../../Views/Claim/Startup/ClaimStartup.ui.js" }
],
"Tests": [
  { "Path" : "ClaimStartup.main.spec.js"}
],
"CodeCoverageExecutionMode": "Always",
"EnableCodeCoverage": "true",
"CodeCoverageIncludes": ["../../Views/Claim/Startup/*"]
}
```

And this file I have placed under my tests folder.
Please let me know what I am missing to configure this properly.

Thanks

Comment: Experts Need your inputs on this

Comment: Can you execute using the command line Chutzpah client with the /coverage flag and see if it generates coverage?

Comment: No it doesnt work, it says TimeOut error, it doesnt recognises the test cases itself, unfortunately I cant share the code as it is project code, i tried with the Samples/Basic to work on my system but it doesnt work

Comment: Can you share a more minimal sample that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Sent you the github sample repository link in the github issues tab